# Reducing the number of OS threads used when have many sleeping threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having a system with hundreds of threads. Most of the thread are sleeping or waiting in a given time but they can wake up whenever they like. I would like to reduce the number of OS threads that are dedicated to my system. 
Do you know about a simple way of doing it? For example, is there a thread pool package that whenever a thread moves to sleep mode, it stores the state and kill the thread. whenever it wakes up, it starts new thread with the state of the old one.

Thanks

Comment: a thread pool wont necessarily reduce the number of threads, it'll just limit the number of threads to some max (assuming a fixed thread pool).

Answer (score 10):

Are you looking for something like [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)?

> An ExecutorService that executes each
>   submitted task using one of possibly
>   several pooled threads, normally
>   configured using Executors factory
>   methods.
>
> Thread pools address two different
>   problems: they usually provide
>   improved performance when executing
>   large numbers of asynchronous tasks,
>   due to reduced per-task invocation
>   overhead, and they provide a means of
>   bounding and managing the resources,
>   including threads, consumed when
>   executing a collection of tasks. Each
>   ThreadPoolExecutor also maintains some
>   basic statistics, such as the number
>   of completed tasks.

Comment: Thread pools are good for many things.. with the details provided, this sounds like the right solution.

Comment: But it's not clear from the OP if the threads contain some info such that they must be kept alive between calls.  In that case I don't think a thread pool is appropriate. (Although a redesign might allow the use of a thread pool.)

Comment: @Daniel. Really? ThreadPools like that sound different to what you were asking for. If a thread in a pool is in the WAITING, TIME_WAITING or BLOCKED (for example from a sleep or IO blocking call), it won't be suspended / killed - it'll be waiting or blocked. That thread will NOT be available to process another task. System resources are taken up when creating threads, so although the thread creation wont be repeated, you can still run out of threads. You seem to be describing something like Comet in your question..?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you described is basically what thread is.

Now, you may know that your application logic only depends on a few variables, not everything on the thread stack. You only needs these few variables to recover from sleep. VM and OS can't know that, and they can't help you.

You must do it yourself. When your thread is about to retire, wrap the essential state up and store it on a queue. Then exit thread, or return it to a thread pool.

When a certain condition is met, lookup the state from the queue, create a new task based on it, and run the task on a new thread.

Answer (score -1):

It's my understanding that you're better off letting the thread sleep, due to the overhead of initializing a new thread. When the thread is sleeping, it won't be scheduled on the CPU, so I guess I don't really see the concern.

Comment: There is a limit to the number of threads that is allowed to exist simultaneously. I don't want to reach it...

Comment: Sleeping is better than a new thread, yes.. but a thread pool solves both problems.